# How do I make a error message appear when a number is types in?

Tags: c#, message

I have set the text box so that only letters can be entered and I would like to know how I can make a error message appear when anything other than a letter is entered. The following is my code:

```
private void FirstName_KeyPress_1(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.KeyChar < 65 || e.KeyChar > 122)
            {

                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        private void FirstName_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            FirstName.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(FirstName_KeyPress_1);

        }
```

I have also tried

```
         if (e.KeyChar < 65 || e.KeyChar > 122)
            {

                e.Handled = true;
            }
else 
{
MessageBox.Show (" Please enter a letter",
                            "Error Message");
}
```

But this message appears once a letter is typed after a number and does not go when "ok" is clicked. It appear about 4 times until it disappears.

Could anyone help me with this please?

Thank you

Comment: Use a MaskedTextBox. Or at least don't assign the event handler on every change, but once, for example in the form's Load event.

Comment: Is this winforms, or a console app, or asp.net, or what?

Comment: @Melanie it is asp.net

Comment: Have you tried a CustomValidator? It won't raise an error until the user moves past the textbox, so that may not be what you want.

Comment: @Melanie I don't really know how to use it as I am new to .net.

Comment: Just Google "asp:CustomValidator". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eee01cx(v=vs.71).aspx will give you basic information and examples.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your placement of this logic. If you want the message to appear when the user clicks the ok/submit button you need to perform a check there and display the message. Your example is checking (and therefor potentially displaying the error message) after every input.

So you want something like;

```
// generate this stub by double clicking the ok/submit button in the GUI builder
private void FirstName_EnterButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      char[] chars = FirstNameTextBox.Text.ToCharArray();
      bool good = true;
      int placeholder;

      for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
      {
           if (int.TryParse(chars[i], placeholder)
           {
                good = false;
                break;
           }
      }
      if (!good)
         MessageBox.Show("Names cannot contain numbers."); 
}
```

A quick explanation of the code - Firstly, we're waiting til the user tries to submit the full input before validating it rather than after each character is added. At this point we convert the input string to a character array and loop over it. `TryParse` returns true if the input is an integer and sets placeholder's value to that integer. If the user has entered an int we go into that if where we change our flag to false then we break since there's no need to continue checking the rest of the string. Outside of the loop we do the `MessageBox.Show`.

Comment: That's a completely long way of doing it that could be shortened tremendously

Comment: @DJKRAZE shorter != better.

Comment: Shorter = Better if you can get the same results based on using already built in functionality / Metods

Comment: Your answer is perfectly fine but I generally disagree with that mentality. Code quality isn't measured by # of lines. Most of the measures taken to shorten code have no purpose and don't make it more readable.

Comment: I am not saying that shorter is better I am saying that the char.IsDigit is an internal function that many coders are not aware of and it's not failed me yet in regards to checking for valid Alpa `A-Z.a-z` characters that's all I am saying.. your code looks just as good I may have opened your eyes to a simpler method which works the same way that your code does my final edited answer takes in account checking all of the values in the TextBox

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use javascript to implement these kindof of functionalities

function isAlphabet(e) {
    var keynum
    var keychar
    var numcheck

```
    if (e.keyCode >= 91 && e.keyCode <= 96)
        return false;
    keynum = e.keyCode
    keychar = String.fromCharCode(keynum)
    numcheck = /[a-zA-z ]/
    return e.returnValue = numcheck.test(keychar);
```

}

You can call the following function Onclientclick event  of the submit button.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use Linq and get a count of Items that are invalid in a List 
do the following

```
string vStr = FirstNameTextBox.Text;
var isValid = (from tmp in vStr
               where char.IsDigit(tmp)
               select tmp).ToList();
```

you can do a

```
ShowMessage(string.Join(",",isValid));
```

`yields 2,3,3,3` in a MessageBox

Comment: @evanmcdonnal it did come up with 4 message boxes

Comment: `user2158786` Think outside the box and the edited code does not come up with 4 it comes up with 1

Comment: @DJKRAZE Sorry i was talking about the code before i was edited.

Comment: Not a problem also that was just an idea of what you could do then I thought I'd show you an alternative way of doing it as well

Comment: you could even go another step and create a Method that checks all of that for you as well as a Customized ShoMessage Method and use the code every where where you want to validate only A-X,a-z characters same works with if you want to check only Numbers add an additional Parameter to your method and pass in true or false that way one method can check both based on setting conditional statement